# LINQ is querying a delete data

Tags: mysql, asp.net, linq

I have a simple select query in linq:

```
var forms = (from fc in db.formscreators
                     where fc.PropertyID == id || fc.PropertyID == 0
                     orderby fc.FormName ascending
                     select fc).ToList();
```

I went to MySQL Workbench and delete a data from formscreators table; however, the LINQ still returning the delete data. Why is it happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Not possible, how exactly are you testing this? Are you sure they are both pointing to the same database? What do you mean by "delete"?

Comment: I'm running my application in debug mode. Yes, same database. What do I mean by "delete"?!? Delete From formscreators Where id = 10

Comment: So you delete and then run this code again? Or do you just check the content of the `forms` variable?

Comment: I delete using SQL in MySQL Workbench (NOT LINQ). Then, I run the code again.

Comment: If I try to delete this odd record using LINQ, it stays running for minutes and can't delete. Looks like some cache issue in the LINQ query

Comment: Are you interrogating the LINQ query result directly? If you are viewing the result in a browser, the result page might be cached. If so, try clearing the cache.